# VBA to import data formatted as matrix in database

Tags: excel, vba

I’m fairly new to VBA - apologies for novice request below..

I have a product code matrix with 18 product names in 1 column as “headers” and 25 version numbers in 1 row as “headers”. The corresponding matrix has entries such as Product1Version1, Product1Version2, etc.

Based on the matrix I want to build a macro that “builds” a price margin database. The price and margin information is formatted as 2 ProductVersion matrices (1 for price, 1 for margin) for each country on a separate sheet (2 examples included).

The database logic should be build with the following logic:

1. Put matrix value 1,1 (Product1Version1) in Cell A2. Cell A1 has the header “ProductVersion”
2. Put the country name in cell B2. Cell B1 has the header name “Country”. The country name is located in cell A1 of each sheet
3. In cell C2, use the vertical and horizontal matrix headers to lookup the “price” value of A2 in the price matrix of the sheet of the corresponding country. Cell C1 has the header “Price”
4. In cell D2, use the vertical and horizontal matrix headers to lookup the “margin” value of A2 in the price matrix of the sheet of the corresponding country. Cell D1 has the header “Margin”
5. Cycle to the next row and repeat for the next matrix value (until all 18*25 values have been entered)

How do I code this in VBA? I attached an example file just in case (https://www.dropbox.com/s/rszf2zr3xryzoud/Example.xlsm?dl=0)

I only know some basic coding. Expect that this the solution involves arrays, but this is beyond my knowledge at the moment

Comment: So on the database sheet you want the price and margin for each country and for each product version?

Comment: This can be done using vlookups and hlookups or other formulas like index match. No need for VBA if I am not wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand why you would think that, but in reality this example is part of a bigger exercise. I didn’t want to make my question too complicated though... For full disclosure: the amount of country sheets is variable, and the data in the country sheets might also be updated with price/margin data for a new year. I want the data input of prior years to remain in the database. This would be difficult through lookup formulas @newguy